# JQuery .hasClass() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seems to me, that I am doing something wrong. So I made a dropdown menu operated by JS code.

So it toggles green class, which makes div block. And now I want to close dropdown by clicking again the same button. I am verifying is there is toggles green class by hasClass() method. But it returns always false. ALWAYS. Why?

JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bg4ev09k/3/
Actual raw code:

```js
$('#loginform').click(function(){
  var container = $(".login");
  if ($(this).hasClass('green'))
  {
    console.log("ere");
    container.hide();
    $(this).removeClass('green');
  } else {
    $('.login').fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
```

```html
<h2><a href="#" id="loginform"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter</a></h2>
<div class="login">
  <div class="arrow-up"></div>
  <div class="formholderauth">
    <div class="randompad">
      <h1>Auth</h1>
      <form action="core/auth/login.php" method="POST">
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин..." value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль...">
        </p>
        <p>
          <button type="submit" name="do_login">Войти</button>
        </p>
      </form>
      <p><a href="/core/auth/signup.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML so we can reproduce your situation.

Comment: Even better, reproduce on jsfiddle or codepen.io

Comment: why not `addClass` when you make `removeClass` in the other condition

Comment: What does `console.log($('[id=loginform]').length)` give inside the click handler? try several times. If it's ever greater than 1, you've got a problem not caused by the given code.

Comment: seems to work fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLqVmX

Comment: works fine here also: https://jsfiddle.net/bg4ev09k/

Comment: @Difster That would not be better. It would be worse. The code should be posted, right here, in a code snippet. 3rd party links can become broken over time and, if that happens, the question is meaningless.

Comment: here's an example of how this problem can occur due to other code on the page: https://jsfiddle.net/6ryw22q7/3/ Miro's fiddle shows a way of fixing this particular problem, but you should still avoid having duplicate id's if this is what is happening.

Comment: the "Evil Code" should check if the id is already set.

Comment: @Sysix wouldn't be Evil anymore

Comment: then use `$(this)` like in your else condition

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try everyone’s tries. If you need actual html-I can either upload Project to hosting or recreate it on jfidle or other platform.

Comment: Your code for me work, post your html.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIBVZL4K818G

Comment: @AndrewGorpenko No need to upload project or recreate it at JS Fiddle. Just edit your question and include the code there. Always, post all relevant code, right here.

Comment: Added all required code.

Comment: Added JFiddle link too. https://jsfiddle.net/bg4ev09k/3/

Answer (score 0):

This "destroy" the Evil code too :)

```js
$(document).on('click','#loginform',function(){
  var container = $(".login");
  if ($(this).hasClass('green')){
    container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
  } else {
    container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).addClass('green');
  }
});

// evil code
$('body').prepend('<div id="loginform"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="green" id="loginform"><i>☺</i> Click me</a>
<div class="login">LOGIN CONTAINER</div>
```

Hope this can be helpful!

**Update**

Sorry for my post.. i was hasty.

With all of the javascript code i found the problem

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
```

This will conflict with this resetting the green class

```
$(document).on('click','#loginform',function(){
    var container = $(".login");
    if ($(this).hasClass('green')){
      container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
      $(this).removeClass('green');
    } else {
      container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
      $(this).addClass('green');
    }
});
```

So by simple adding `&& !$('#loginform').is(e.target)` you resolve the problem

Here is the code

```js
$('button[type="submit"]').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#2ecc71');
});

$('button[type="submit"]').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#1abc9c');
});

$(document).on('click','#loginform',function(){
  var container = $(".login");
  if ($(this).hasClass('green')){
    container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
  } else {
    container.stop().fadeToggle('slow');
    $(this).addClass('green');
  }
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
  var container = $(".login");

  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0
    && !$('#loginform').is(e.target)
    ) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
      container.hide();
      $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #2E3192;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #2E3192, #1BFFFF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #2E3192, #1BFFFF);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #2E3192, #1BFFFF);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2E3192, #1BFFFF);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

.menu h2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.menu h2 a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu h2 a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

.auth {
  float: right;
}

.signup {
  margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.login {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

.reg {
  width: 400px;
}

/*Auth*/

.formholderauth {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.formholderauth input[type="text"], .formholderauth input[type="password"] {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  background-color: #ececec;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #A7A9A9;
}

.formholderauth input[type="text"]:focus, .formholderauth input[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #1abc9c;
}

.formholderauth button[type="submit"] {
  background: #1abc9c;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.formholderauth button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #1bc6a4;
}

.formholderauth p {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.formholderauth p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.formholderauth a {
  color: #1abc9c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.formholderauth a:hover {
  color: 
  color: #10EE30;
}

.randompad {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="loginform"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter</a></h2>
<div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <div class="formholderauth">
        <div class="randompad">
            <h1>Auth</h1>
            <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login...">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password...">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" name="do_login">Auth</button>
                </p>
            </form>
            <p><a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reg</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I still apologize for my rush. Have a good day

Comment: Please add an explanation of the problem and how you fixed it, rather than just dumping code on us.

Comment: Without the OPs HTML, we can't say that your answer is helpful or not.